# what is the meaning of inteface speed -1?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, interface

I have a physical server with 6 interfaces: eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4, eno49, and eno50.
The eno49 and eno50 are up and when I check their capacity for example with `ethtool eno49` or from `cat /sys/class/net/eno49/speed`, they show that there are 10G up.
But I want to know the capacity of other interfaces which are down. To check that I assign them an IP address like 172.29.1.11 with  `ifconfig eno1 172.29.1.11` and then use `cat /sys/class/net/eno1/speed` and the result is -1.
I don't know what is does it mean.
If I want to check whether the interface capacity is 1g, how can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

**Hi**

I do greatly **appreciate** your **turn** here.

> If I want to check whether the interface capacity is 1g, how can I do
> it?

So you could achieve interface capacity result via below command:

```
dmesg | grep eno1
```

OR

```
ethtool eno1
```

It's work like charm, Have great day future friend.

Comment: I had just provided best possible answer according to your question , i hope you get it work with above command , i think so you could work around `eno1` uplink , ping me via this communication method here if you need any future tips ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).